# CAShapeLayer to UILabel hides text

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am trying to add a `CAShapeLayer` to `UILabel`.
The issue is: the text disappears after doing so:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
item.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850149/adding-a-cggradient-as-sublayer-to-uilabel-hides-the-text-of-label or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962668/hide-text-with-a-shape-mask-swift ?

Comment: i tried both it was not helping me

Comment: the easy way is to use two UIViews, reason from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7209543/4222801)

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue, by adding Lable into **UIView**, And We have to **insert layer** like below

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPat
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
item.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
```

**item** object will be your **UIView**

I was tried to **addLayer** so it was not working as excepted.

```
item.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```